# PHP: $_POST fields empty

Tags: html, php

I'm trying to submit a simple form via e-mail, but when I get the e-mail though, the $_POST fields are not populated and the message body comes out as: "Name: Email: Organization: Role:" with no data. Any ideas?

HTML file:

```
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="contactForm"     action="submit_contact.php"></div>
        <div class="modal hide fade in" id="contactModal">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                <h3>Submit form</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div style='display:none'></div>

                <fieldset>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="name" type="text" name="name" maxlength="75" />
                            <p class="help-block" id="name_error"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">E-mail</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="email" type="text" name="email" maxlength="75" />
                            <p class="help-block" id="email_error"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Organization</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="organization" type="text" name="organization" maxlength="75" />
                            <p class="help-block" id="organization_error"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Role</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select name="occupation" id="id_occupation">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="MD">Medical Devices - Sales & Marketing</option>
<option value="MO">Medical Devices - Other</option>
<option value="MD">Physician</option>
<option value="OT">Other</option>
</select>
                            <p class="help-block" id="occupation_error"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="height:30px">
                <a name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" id="contactSubmit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="#">
                    Submit
                </a>
                <p style="text-align: left; margin-top:6px;" id="contactFormStatus"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
$('#contactSubmit').on('click', function(e){
  // We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
    e.preventDefault();

    // Find form and submit it
    $('#contactForm').submit();
});
</script>
```

submit_contact.php:

```
<?php 
$ToEmail = 'xxx@xxx.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Site contact form'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["name"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "\nEmail: ".$_POST["email"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "\nOrganization: ".$_POST["organization"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "\nRole: ".$_POST["occupation"]."";
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?>
```

Comment: Fixed the 'request' to 'post', but that wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the form tags into the modal body ended up solving it. Didn't expect that to be the solution, but oh well.

Comment: how do you mean? did you move the tag to the top of the page? I have the same problem..

Answer (score 6):

```
<form method="request">
```

should be

```
<form method="post">
```

Comment: Sorry, actually mis-pasted the code. It was post. That wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML form method to post instead of request

form method="request" ...

to

form method="post" ...

Comment: Not relevant - fixed this already

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know "method" should be "post", but you can access it with $_REQUEST

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="contactForm"     action="submit_contact.php"> </div>
```

Validate your HTML, you have a random closing div

Comment: Thanks, but didn't seem to fix much.